# Both TSV and TXT output in tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract to perform OCR in Python.
I want to have the TSV file to do some analysis on the confidence level, but also the text file with the read text.
However the only way to get both outputs is to run tesseract twice, which is time consuming:

```
tesseract input_image out_text -l eng
tesseract input_image out_tsv -l eng tsv
```

Is there currenctly a way to create both outputs in one execution?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Try:

`tesseract input_image out tsv txt`

It's not necessary to specify `-l eng` as it's the default language.

Comment: thanks works fine! do you possibly also know how to give different names to the tsv and to the txt?

Comment: No, they will have the same common base name. You'd have to run two separate commands, or rename one of the output files.

Answer (score 2):

You should write the config lines manually like that :

`tesseract input_image out -c tessedit_create_tsv=1 -c tessedit_create_txt=1`

Comment: I am also passing extra flags like --tessdata-dir  etc and only this option worked for me